# What is difference between `$*` an `$@` in Bash

Tags: arrays, bash, parameters

I always use `$@` when I want all arguments of bash function but recently I just found that `$*` also works in the same way, and it also can use as array index.

My question is What is difference between `$*` an `$@` in Bash? and which one should I prefer?

Comment: See http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_05_02

Comment: To see the difference, try using an argument containing a space, e.g.: `myscript.sh "a b c" d`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [Bash manual](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/internalvariables.html) is quite clear on this topic:

> - `$*`
>
>   All of the positional parameters, seen as a single word.
>
>   Note: `$*` must be quoted.
> - `$@`
>
>   Same as `$*`, but each parameter is a quoted string, that is, the parameters are passed on intact, without interpretation or expansion. This means, among other things, that each parameter in the argument list is seen as a separate word.
>
>   Note: Of course, `$@` should be quoted.

Comment: How about `$1`, `$2` ...? should I also quote them?

Comment: @terces907 ideally, yes. However, if you know for sure that each argument doesn't contain characters from your IFS, you don't need to. As a side note `echo $*` and `echo $@` without any quotation are equivalent

Comment: See  further http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-variable

Comment: @terces907 generally, you should quote *everything* in bash unless you know what you are doing. Variables or backticks not embedded in double quotes will have unwanted "features" in most cases.

Answer (score 2):

There is a historical development here. `$*` was  found to be insufficient, and so `$@` was introduced to replace it. There are still situations where `$*` is useful; but unless you specifically want to break up quoted tokens, you should avoid it.